# filter array by curent date to last 365 days in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
    [{"Name":"HAINES","CreatedDate":"2019-09-03T12:21:53.000Z"},{"Name":"JONES, ","CreatedDate":"2019-09-03T12:21:53.000Z"}]
```

```java
filterbyDaysarray: function(Dataarray) {
        console.log('Dataarray....' + JSON.stringify(Dataarray));

        var endDate = $A.localizationService.formatDate(new Date(), "YYYY-MM-DD");
        console.log('endDate....' + endDate);

        var sixtydaysresult = new Date();
        sixtydaysresult.setDate(sixtydaysresult.getDate() - 365);
        
        var startDate = $A.localizationService.formatDate(sixtydaysresult, "YYYY-MM-DD");
        console.log('startDate....' + startDate);

        var resultfilteredarray = Dataarray.filter(a => {
            var date = new Date(a.CreatedDate);
            return (date >= startDate && date <= endDate);
        });
        console.log('resultfilteredarray....' + resultfilteredarray);
    }
```

above are records which i am fetching with using above code but there is null Please Review it tell where i am making mistake

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Can I suggest you [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/315795/edit) the question to add an example of the JSON.stringify(Dataarray) so readers can see what data is being processed here? The most important detail would be what the CreatedDate property values are. Additionally, full detail of the error seen would be useful.

Comment: Done that please  review it

Comment: Please add the full detail of any error seen as well.

Comment: Not getting error just null value in console

Comment: Null value for what? Perhaps you could list the console log outputs and highlight the one showing null that is worrying you?

Comment: resultfilteredarray....                                          This is i am getting while running last console in mycode

Comment: That suggests that the filters are not being matched. Is there a reason you don't simply compare Date instances? (Why convert to a string for comparison?)

Comment: You can't get a "null" from Array.prototype.filter. Do you mean to say the list is empty?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to compare a Date to a string, which is why it fails. There's no need to use the localization service to convert the dates to strings.

```
let endDate = new Date();
let startDate = new Date(endDate.getTime()-(365*8.64e7));
let resultfilteredarray = Dataarray.filter(a => {
        var date = new Date(a.CreatedDate);
        return (date >= startDate && date <= endDate);
    });
```